# How to disable encrypting the password in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to disable encrypting the password in wordpress,I want to store password as it is that user enter.Can you give me any suggestion.
How should i do that

Comment: This is a question best addressed to the wordpress forum itself.  If it is your own server, wordpress is nothing more than a mysql database and a collection of php files.  You could find the account creation code, and store the passwords in the clear in your own custom field.  Then you would not need to modify the login code.  Hopefully you are aware that what you propose is a very bad idea for security reasons.  As much as you might want to know what people's passwords are, if you can know them, then a hacker might get them, too.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this would be possible by overriding the function qa_db_calc_passcheck (from qa-db-users.php) and simply returning the password instead of hashing it. See [here](http://docs.question2answer.org/plugins/overrides/) for how to do function overrides.

However, I would strongly recommend against doing that, as it is grossly insecure to have passwords stored in plaintext in the database.